# Program type already present: android.support.v4

Tags: android, react-native

i am trying to build my react native project on android but i got this error message.

i tryed to fixe libraries dependency but does not work.i found a post that suggest to exclude "android.support.v4.app ..". but don't really know how to handle that any idea
    this is package i load

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-fs')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-resizer')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation project(':react-native-restart')
    implementation project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation project(':react-native-cardview')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'

}


this is the result
" com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
  Learn how to resolve the issue at.
  Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel
"
```

Comment: how did you fix it? I stuck with same issue